# Retrieve and store XML attributes in a PHP Array

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML string like this in a PHP variable. This string is generated through a REST request to a service using nusoap in PHP

```
<exception name="xyz.TestException" message="Invalid Username.jake"/>
```

How do I use PHP to retrieve the XML string attributes in an array, so I can use them for messaging purposes?

```
Ex: The result PHP array should look like this.
$attrArray = array();
$attrArray["name"]= "xyz.TestException" 
$attrArray["message"] = "Invalid Username.jake"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). See the 5th example.

Comment: Are you getting the complete XML (with <?xml version...?> header) or just a part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, not very clean:

```
    $string = '<exception name="xyz.TestException" message="Invalid Username.jake"/>';

    $parser = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
    $attrs  = array();
    // Convert attributes to string
    foreach($parser->attributes() as $key => $value)
            $attrs[$key] = "$value"; // Object to string conversion using quotes

    print_r($attrs);
```

You can also directly and more cleanly access `$parser["name"]` and `$parser["message"]`.